# iTunes Connect: Pending An Apple Release

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

My app has gone from In Review (Yellow) to Pending An Apple Release (red). I couldn't find anything on this combo in the docs. I set my app release date for immediately and its price tier is free.

Thoughts?

EDIT: Since others brought this up, my app is also targeting 7.0

EDIT: App has been approved without me doing anything. Side note it's not appearing in search but the direct link works.

Comment: This is funny, the same thing is happening to me right now and I do not understand why either, since my binary build target is set to iOS 7.0, which everybody knows has been released in late 2013. I sent an inquiry to apple and I'm currently waiting for a response.

Comment: I'm in the same boat as you and Thomas. I also sent an inquiry to apple. Best thing to do now is just wait.

Comment: Sundays answer would be correct in a typical scenario. But something strange is going on here, because I know my build target is 7.0 as does Thomas. I suspect maybe apple has some internal reason for holding on to apps maybe until they release an ios version update for that [ios 7 security flaw](http://9to5mac.com/2014/04/03/ios-7-bug-allows-anyone-to-disable-find-my-iphone-and-bypass-activation-lock-without-a-password/) with being able to disable find my iphone.

Comment: It is also being talk at the Apple Developer Forums https://devforums.apple.com/message/956464

Answer (score 2):

Per https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH30-SW1

The "pending an Apple Release" means:

> Apple is holding your app version until the corresponding Apple iOS or OS version is released to the public.
>   If you think an app should be released on existing iOS or OS versions, review the deployment target set in your app binary. If you rebuild your app binary with a different deployment target, reject the binary for this version and submit the new version.

Sounds like you need to review the deployment target and if you change it, reject the binary and re-submit. If you need help with rejecting the binary, please let me know.

Hope this helps!